# Call .Net controller action from JS file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to reach this action method in Apicontroller, but it is never reached.
Instead I get the 404 error.

This is the JS file

```
function getToken(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/GetToken',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            data: params,
            success: launchParams => {
                resolve(launchParams);
            },
            error: err => {
                console.log('Error in getting token!', err);
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And this is my action method

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
    //other actions ...

    [Route("GetToken")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("text/plain")]
    [Produces("text/plain")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetToken()
    {
        //some code...
    }
}
```

**Note**: I'm using razor pages, the JS function is used for all my pages to get the token.

Comment: the APIcontroller is in the same project. It should be supposed to work at https://localhost:44350/api/GetToken

Comment: You are sending `data: params` in your JS, but your API action doesn't handle that. A common cause of 404 is wrong signature.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. But at the end I read the Request.Body into a StreamReader to get the data.
The strange thing here is that this same code (JS and controller) work fine for .Net Core 2.1, but not for .Net Core 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ApiController in a razor page project,you need to configure routing like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
}
```

So that your ApiController will be called.

Comment: the c# code is for .Net Core 6

This is what I have in my program.cs file

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: yes, it worked, just added it into my program.cs file plus "builder.Services.AddControllers();"